# How can I migrate pdf repository with file titles?

Tags: migrations, media

I've a large amount of files to be migrated, stored in a folder under my Drupal root folder. 
My source schema is a Mysql table like this:

```
id (PK)
dmname
dmfilename
tid
dmdate_published
```

I want to store them like entities of type 'file' and bundle 'document' and they will be not attached to nodes. The bundle document has a taxonomy custom field.

I wrote this migration class in a Migrate custom module:

```
class TabellaDocmanMigration extends Migration {
    public function __construct(array $arguments = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($arguments);
        $this->description = t('Migrazione base dati componente Docman di Joomla.');
        $query = db_select('jos_docman', 'j')
            ->fields('j', array(
                'id',
                'dmname',
                'dmfilename',
            ));
        $query->addExpression("UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dmdate_published)", 'dmdate_published');
        $query->innerJoin('docman_pivot', 'd', 'd.id_docman = j.catid');
        $query->fields('d', array('tid'));
        $query->condition('published', 1, '=');
        $query->condition('approved', 1, '=');
        $query->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
        $query->range(0,2);
        $this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query);
        $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationFile('document');
        $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
            array(
                'id' => array(
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'not null' => true,
                    'description' => 'ID del file originale',
                ),
            ),
            MigrateDestinationFile::getKeySchema()
        );

        // My source directory
        $this->addFieldMapping('source_dir')
            ->defaultValue('sites/default/files/dmdocuments');

        // My source file.
        $this->addFieldMapping('value', 'dmfilename');

        // My destination.
        $this->addFieldMapping('destination_dir')
            ->defaultValue('public://media-root');
        $this->addFieldMapping('destination_file', 'dmfilename');

        // My fields
        $this->addFieldMapping('timestamp', 'dmdate_published');
        $this->addFieldMapping('field_folder', 'tid');
        $this->addFieldMapping('field_folder:source_type')
            ->defaultValue('tid');

        $this->addFieldMapping('uid')
            ->defaultValue(1);

        $this->addFieldMapping('preserve_files')->defaultValue(FALSE);
        $this->addFieldMapping('pathauto')->defaultValue(0);

    }
}
```

The class works well but I can't migrate file name (as title). Ex:

```
id (PK) -> 842
dmname -> My file name like a title
dmfilename -> my_file_uri.pdf
tid -> 18
dmdate_published -> 1486371655
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks